# How can I get access to values in input fields inside Angular Directive test?

Tags: angularjs

I have a Jasmine test for my angular controller with the following function:

```
function compileDirective() {
        var body = '<div class="col-sm-4">' + 
'<input id="email" type="email" ng-model="form.email" value="test@test.com" field-match="emailsMatch()">' + '</div>';
        var tpl = '<form name="myForm">' + body  + '</form>';

        inject(function($compile) {
            var form = $compile(tpl)(scope);
            elem = form.find('div');
        });
        function emailsMatch() {
          //do some logic in here, depending on the value of the email field
        }

        scope.$digest();
    }
```

I want to be able to create another function inside the compileDirective function (emailsMatch()) which looks at the value in the input field and does some logic using it. I don't know how to access the input field though. I have a handle to elem which is the entire html starting with the . How can I look at the value of the input field?

Answer (score 1):

To access `emailsMatch` function,you should make it a part of the `scope`.On the other hand, if you have `ng-model="form.email"` written in your markup, I assume you have `form`(with `email`property inside) property in your `scope`. So you need something like this:

```
scope.emailsMatch = function() {
   console.log( scope.form.email ); //should print value of the <input>
};
```